HLSL Shader, Unreal- Float seems to cause performance problems
I'm building a shader in Unreal using HLSL, and the final piece of it looks something like this-
// Check un-overlapped ranges
for (int r = 0; r < range_count; r++) {
    if (combined_spheres[r].y != -1) continue;

    index = intersecting_spheres[combined_spheres[r].x];
    radius = all_spheres[index].w;

    b_length = sphere_extras[index].x - sphere_extras[index].y;
    
    c = b_length / (2 * radius);
    c *= c;

    maxY = max_coeff * c * c * (8*c + 5);
    found_surface = maxY > Threshold;
}

return found_surface;

Anything I do to try and return the value of found_surface causes severe performance problems. Here are a couple examples-
    maxY = max(sign(max_coeff * c * c * (8*c + 5) - Threshold), 0);

    // Store for later
    found_surface = min(maxY + found_surface, 1.0);
}

return found_surface;

    maxY = max_coeff * c * c * (8*c + 5);
    found_surface = maxY > Threshold;

    if(found_surface) return 1;
}

return 0;

I tried changing found_surface from a float to a bool, but that didn't make a difference- from what I understand, all data types are vectors in HLSL, so that wasn't totally surprising.
I played with [flatten] and [branch] as well but, had no luck with them either. But then, from what I understand, returning a value shouldn't count as a branch, so I'm a bit confused.
The strangest thing to me is, I make use of branched early returns several times before this in this script-
if (intersections == 0) return 0;

if (range_data[0].x * range_data[0].x > nearest_surface) return 0;

-which haven't ever given me any performance problems. What might be going on here?
